# How do you select specific range in a string using RegEx

Tags: regex

So I have a string. Let's say for the argument it is this one:

```
1234567891113SomeTextExample
```

I want to have two regular expresions:

1. Select from beginning to, say, 6th position;
2. Select from 8th position to 12th position.

I know how to select everything AFTER specific position, e.g.:

```
(?<=.{6})(.*)$
```

would select everything after 5 characters.

I am using Sublime Text editor and need to cleanup some logs and these two expressions would save a whole lot of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `^` to get your regex to start at the beginning.

**Beginning to 6th position : `^(.{6})`**

```js
var str = 'xdcfvgbhdsds';
var regex = /^(.{6})/;
console.log(regex.exec(str)[1]);
```

**8th to 12th position : `^.{7}(.{5})`**

```js
var str = 'xdcfvgbhddsfsffsds';
var regex = /^.{7}(.{5})/;
console.log(regex.exec(str)[1]);
```

Comment: `I am using Sublime Text editor` ... it seems the OP is not using JavaScript.

Comment: Fair enough, nothing wrong with a demo (I also added one).

Comment: First one works great, thank you for that! But the second one just gives me first 12 characters....

Comment: I will have to figure out this one on my own then. Still a big help!

Answer (score 2):

Beginning to 6th position ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GxTb08/1)):

```
^(.{6}).*$
```

Characters 8 to 12, inclusive on both ends ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GxTb08/2)):

```
^.{7}(.{5}).*$
```

I am assuming here that you want to capture these specific ranges for some sort of use.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found it out.

First one - Select from beginning to, say, 6th position:

```
^(.{6})
```

Thanks Zenoo for this.

And select from 8th position to 12th position:

```
^(.{8})|(?<=.{12})(.*)$
```

Well, at least this one works in Sublime Text. I am sure there are lots and lots of editors/applications which are fine with Zenoo's approach (`^.{7}(.{5})`).